# Any way to open Windows Mobility Center with Win+X in Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, quicklaunch, windows-mobility-center

In Windows Vista, 7, 8, and 8.1, the user could simply press Win+X to instantly display the Windows Mobility Center.

In Windows 10, Microsoft changed things, and the Win+X keyboard shortcut displays, by default, the lengthy context menu for the Start Menu.

Is there any way, in Windows 10, to restore the functionality of Win+X to instantly display the Windows Mobility Center?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have the Windows Mobility Center disabled and the default <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> is that context menu.

In order to [enable it](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/92301-enable-disable-windows-mobility-center-windows-10-a.html) you can:

- Enable it in the Local Group Policy (Windows 10 Pro, Entreprise and Education only)

The entry is located at `Computer Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Windows Mobility Center`, double-click "Turn off Windows Mobility Center", click Disable and save.

- Registry

You will need to modify the DWORD `NoMobilityCenter` to blank (1 to disable) under these two directories

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\MobilityCenter

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\MobilityCenter
```

After these changes are made, the shortcut is reserved to the WMC and also accessible in the context menu. [Open Windows Mobility Center in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/115279-open-windows-mobility-center-windows-10-a.html)